# JQuery on adding to optgroup trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a select box which contains an optgroup. I need to add an event listener to it such as onclick, or onchange that will fire an event, but only when I add a new option into it.

Here's how I'm selecting it:

```
var $selectedExam = $("#formExam_released"); //this is the <optgroup>
```

I tried

```
$selectedExam.on("change", function(){
        removeDuplicates('exam');
    });
```

but that will trigger "removeDuplicates" only when I click on an item in the optgroup.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you adding items to your select? Where's the code?

Comment: You want to trigger this function, without user-interaction as well?

Comment: you can't use event listeners on children of select in IE. It does not work. Filter your values instead when change occurs on select. Provide some html and code that adds options. Why can't you check for duplicates before adding?

Comment: Well, I can't filter it before because I am supposed to have duplicates until one of them is selected. We have Exams, and we have pre-exams. Both contain the same exams, but you can't have the same pre-exam and exam.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("optgroup").each(function() {
        $(this).on("change", function() {
            var id = $(this).attr(id);
            var arrrayOfElements = [];

            $("optgroup").each(function() {
                if($(this).attr("id") == id) {
                    $(this + " option").each(function() {
                        arrrayOfElements[arrrayOfElements.length] = $(this).val();
                    });
                }
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < arrrayOfElements.length; i++) {
                for(var j = 0; j < arrrayOfElements.length; j++) {
                    if(arrrayOfElements[i] == arrrayOfElements[j]) {
                        $("optgroup option[value='"+ arrrayOfElements[i] +"']").each(function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This code should remove all duplicated from the select options. This could be trigerred on the `.on("change",...);`

After edit, as long you add attribute ID with unique identifier you could search for this value.

Comment: flaw in code, `$("optgroup option")` will find all options, not just the ones in specific optgroup

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. As long the optgroup has an id, we can store the id to the variable and later store only values of the options only from the specified optgroup. I'm just fetching this in my head, please point out any other errors.

Comment: still buggy, won't work in most versions of IE, if any. Would bind to select and use `$(this).find()` for subsets

Comment: I fixed few things. I'll just leave it here as a concept, then :)